# Custom text on map from Mapbox.js

Tags: javascript, mapbox

I am using the mapbox js api to draw a few cricles on a map and I would like to add a text to explain what the circle represents. In this case, each circle shows how far you can walk in 5 minutes, 10 minutes and so on.

I want the text to be just a text not a marker (not clickable) but I can't find any way to do this. Does anyone know if this is possible?

**Update**
To clarify, what I want to do is add a custom text like "New York" in this example https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/marker-popup-onload/

Comment: Yes, this is possible.

Comment: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/ popup on load looks like what need - their docs are ace.

Comment: I updated the question to illustrate what I want to do

Comment: The "New York" in your example isn't custom text, it's part of the map tiles.

Comment: I am aware of that but I would like to add a custom text simular to the "New York" text.

Comment: A fun hacky way to do it is to create the custom text out of lines in your mapbox tile project, then load in the geojson

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can add a [custom legend](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/custom-legend/) instead to explain the circles, i.e.:

```
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'examples.map-y7l23tes');
map.legendControl.addLegend('... legend html ...');
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use custom markers to display whatever you want against a point.

[Custom Markers](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/custom-marker-tooltip/)

then just use the following to iterate each layer and open its popup as described in your example. this means you wont have to click on it to open it.

```
marker.eachLayer(function(m) {
  m.openPopup();
});
```